# start an iphone app from within another iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is it possible to write a function in an iphone app A that when you click on a button within that app A it will close app A and automaticall open up App B

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Custom URL schemes.

Nice tutorial here http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html